# Promises and async await is not working -Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise { <rejected> 'noData' } reason: undefined - node.js

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, try-catch

I'm stuck past few days I'm using openshift modules to fetch all the pods and their status using node.js

```
npm i okd-api
```

Following is the snippet to fetch the pod list

```
                    aws_app.get('/fetchList', async function(req,res){
                            await getServices().then((allServices)=>{
                                console.log("allServices",allServices)
                                res.send(allServices)       
                    })
                    .catch((err)=>{throw err;})
                    })

                    async function getServices(){
                        return await new Promise(async (resolve,reject)=>{
                            let config = {
                                cluster:'master openshift url',
                                user: 'username',
                                password: 'password',
                                    strictSSL:  false  
                            }
                            let WMArr=[];
                            let resArr=[]  ;
                            await  login(config)
                                    .then(async(okd) =>{
                                        console.log("okd",okd)                                            
                                        await  okd.namespace('namespaceHere')
                                               .pod
                                               .watch_all( async(pods) =>{
                                                      console.log("pods",pods)                                                                                                        
                                                        await pods.map((v)=>
                                                        {                                                                                                                                                            
                                                            if(!WMArr.includes(v.object.metadata.labels.app))
                                                            {
                                                                let obj={"name":v.object.metadata.labels.app,"Instance":WMArr.lastIndexOf(v.object.metadata.labels.app)===WMArr.indexOf(v.object.metadata.labels.app)?1:WMArr.lastIndexOf(v.object.metadata.labels.app)+1,"Status":v.object.status.phase}
                                                                resArr.push(obj);                                                                       
                                                            }       
                                                            WMArr.push(v.object.metadata.labels.app); 
                                                            console.log("WMArr",WMArr,"resArr",resArr)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                        }); 
                                                 })
                                                if(resArr!==null &&resArr!== undefined&& resArr.length1==0){
                                                    resolve(resArr)
                                                }else{
                                                    reject("not found")
                                                }
                                    })                     
                                   .catch(err => {throw err})                            
                        })
                        .then((state) => {
                            console.log("state",state)
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log("erdfkkg",error)
                        });
                    }
```

I'm going wrong somewhere the promise never gets resolved.IC, the results in console.log 
Is my approach wrong please do correct me
Can anyone lemme know as to where I'm going wrong
I'm yet not able to achieve the result 
 No matter what following error is thrown

**Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise {  'noData' } reason: undefined**

```
                 aws_app.get('/fetchList',  function(req,res){
                           getServices().then((allServices)=>{
                                console.log("allServices",allServices)
                                res.send(allServices)       
                    })
                    .catch((err)=>{throw err;})
                    })

                          async function getServices(){
                    let arrRes=[];
                    try{
                        let prom= new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
                             let config = {
                                cluster:'master openshift url',
                                user: 'username',
                                password: 'password',
                                    strictSSL:  false  
                            }
                            let allpodsData=   login(config)
                                    .then(async (okd) =>{
                                        console.log("okd",okd)   
                                let nnn= new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{ 
                                    okd.namespace('namespacename').pod.watch_all((pods) =>{
                                                console.log("pods",pods)   
                                                arrRes.push(pods);                            
                                        })?resolve(arrRes):reject("noData");

                                        });  
                                let res= await nnn;
                                if(res)resolve(res);
                                else reject("No data")                                                                           
                                    /*if(arrRes!==null &&arrRes!== undefined&& arrRes.length!==0){
                                            resolve(arrRes);}
                                            else reject("No data")*/

                                    })                     
                                .catch(err => {throw err})  

                            })
                            let result = await prom;
                            alert(result)
                    } 
                    catch(err){console.log("err",err)
                    throw err;}           
                    }
```

No matter I use async/awiat, promises, then catch I dont get the result.
first the promise rejects then the promise resolves

Follwoing causes the issue not returning after its resolved, returns before it resolve so no data. the following returns a promise I'm not sure of how to handle it can anyone plese help me out

```
                    okd.namespace('namespacename').pod.watch_all((pods) =>{
                                                console.log("pods",pods)   
                                                arrRes.push(pods);                            
                                        })?resolve(arrRes):reject("noData");
```

Is my approach wrong please do correct me
Can anyone lemme know as to where I'm going wrong

Comment: Whats your console log printing and where do you need help?

Comment: Don't mix `.then(..).catch(..)` with async/await, choose one and stick to it.

Comment: It appears you're trying to use `await` with functions that don't return a promise.  That will do NOTHING useful at all and the `await` won't actually `await`.  `await` ONLY does something useful if you are awaiting a promise.  It seems unlikely that `okd.namespace().pod.watch_all()` returns a promise.  It seems unlikely that `pods.map()` returns a promise.   This is just a complete misuse and misunderstanding of `async/await`.  Please go read about how it actually works.

Comment: console.log("WMArr",WMArr,"resArr",resArr)  results are reflecting on the prompt later before that the reject error is display its not waiting for the result set to resolve

Comment: @root I'd used then catch it did not work not just async /await nor the both work I'm not sure why is it not wait

Comment: @jfriend00   please share some link where I can get clear idea. I'd not used async-await  beacuse their was not wait for the results I'd used it . I use it or not its the same thing

Comment: To use `await` properly, ALL your asynchronous operations need to be using promises, not plain callbacks.  These days, most libraries offer you a promise interface - you just have to switch your code over to using it.  If not, for some odd reason, then you have to "promisify" the interface yourself, either manually or with `util.promisify()`.

Comment: Plus it makes no sense to `await` things that are purely synchronous such as `pods.map()`.  That's just regular synchronous code.  There are hundreds of references on how to properly use `await` that you can find with Google, but your code needs more restructuring than just that.  You need to do some learning about asynchronous programming in node.js, more than I can offer in a comment or answer here.

Comment: Okay thanx @jfriend00

Comment: @ZunaibImtiaz I know :(. But I need to do  that working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following works

```
               let fetchListarr=[];
                    aws_app.get('/path', async (req,res) =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Promise.all(promisesArray).then(values => {
                            // do stuff with values here
                            console.log("fetchList",values);
                            res.send(values)
                            });   
                        }
                        catch (e){throw e;}
                    });
                    var WMArr=[];
                    var prom1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {      
                            let config = {
                            cluster:'clusterurl',
                            user: 'username',
                            password: 'passowrd',
                            strictSSL:  false  
                            };
                            login(config)
                                        .then(okd=>{
                                            okd.namespace('namespace').pod.watch_all(pods=>{
                                                    pods.map((v)=> {                                                                                                                                                            
                                                            if(!WMArr.includes(v.object.metadata.labels.app))
                                                                {   let obj={"TargetServiceName":v.object.metadata.labels.app,"Instance":WMArr.lastIndexOf(v.object.metadata.labels.app)===WMArr.indexOf(v.object.metadata.labels.app)?1:WMArr.lastIndexOf(v.object.metadata.labels.app)+1,"Status":v.object.status.phase}
                                                                        fetchListarr.push(obj);                                                                       
                                                                }       
                                                            WMArr.push(v.object.metadata.labels.app);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                            }); 
                                                    })
                                                    setTimeout(function() {                      
                                                    resolve( fetchListarr);                           
                                                    }, 5000);
                                            })
                                        .catch(err=>{throw err}) 
                        });
                    var promisesArray= [prom1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this runs,Correct few bit if you see compile errors,

```
   aws_app.get('/fetchList', async (req,res) =>
  {
    try
    {
        const allServices = await getServices();
        console.log("allServices",allServices);
        res.send(allServices);
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

   });



  async function getServices()
  {
    let config = {
        cluster: 'master openshift url',
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        strictSSL: false
    };

    let WMArr = [];
    let resArr = [];

    try
    {
        const okd = await login(config);
        console.log('okd', okd);

        await  okd.namespace('namespaceHere')
            .pod
            .watch_all((pods) =>
            {
                console.log("pods",pods);
               await pods.map((v)=>
                {
                    if(!WMArr.includes(v.object.metadata.labels.app))
                    {
                        let obj={"name":v.object.metadata.labels.app,"Instance":WMArr.lastIndexOf(v.object.metadata.labels.app)===WMArr.indexOf(v.object.metadata.labels.app)?1:WMArr.lastIndexOf(v.object.metadata.labels.app)+1,"Status":v.object.status.phase}
                        resArr.push(obj);
                    }
                    WMArr.push(v.object.metadata.labels.app);
                    console.log("WMArr",WMArr,"resArr",resArr)
                });
            });

        if (resArr == null || resArr == 'undefined' || resArr.length == 0)
        {

           throw  new Error("Not Found");
        }

        return resArr;
    }
    catch (e)
    {
       throw e;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't c the results   res.send(allServices);    //////////////okd.namespace('namespaceHere')
            .pod
            .watch_all((pods) => */////////// -------> this returns a promise and that need to handle but I'm not sure of that

Comment: So now you need to figure out what pods returns. I think execution is working fine now

Comment: @Tested updated line `await pods.map((v)=>` with `await`

Comment: i get the same result if i execute the code which I've pasted in my question  the only thing is I dont get it here ///***res.send(allServices)***// cause this is executing first and not waiting for that function to return

Comment: yeah It makes not difference that gets the result the same way which my does